# Convert all cells in a matrix to time format in R

Tags: r, datetime, matrix

I have a large matrix full of times in character format like this

```
a <- as.matrix(c("18:12:30", "6:15:30", "12:31:40"))
b <- as.matrix(c("1:50:30", "9:50:32", "5:30:43"))
c <- as.matrix(c("7:54:23", "22:45:34", "12:54:23"))
mat <- cbind(a,b,c)
```

I would like to convert each of the values to a time format. I know I could do it row by row using

```
a <- strptime(a, "%H:%M:%OS")
b <- strptime(b, "%H:%M:%OS")
c <- strptime(b, "%H:%M:%OS")
```

But I have a large matrix, so I'm looking for a function that could do this even if I have many more columns and rows.

Comment: This is time, not date.

Comment: Thanks for catching that, I updated the original post.

Comment: strptime(mat, "%H:%M:%OS") is okay.

Comment: @VenYao Except that `strptime` inserts today's date, which is probably not what the OP wants.

Comment: @alistaire The op's original way, 'do it row by row' will also insert today's date. I think the matrix rather than 'insert todays date' is what the OP really cares about.

Comment: @VenYao The original attempt wasn't correct, either. It changes the meaning of your values, and will get a different result if you run it on a different day, or try to do anything with it, which makes it only useful if you're very aware of its structure and are willing to hack around it. There are better ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beware of how your time and date data is stored. `strptime` converts to `POSIXlt`, which always includes a date, so `strptime` inserts today's date if you don't specify one. That can create huge reproducibility problems.

Instead, you need to use a package to get a suitable time data structure. `chron` has a nice simple one. To recreate a `data.frame` of times (matrices can only store numbers):

```
library(chron)

# lapply chron over the columns of your data; collect in data.frame
time_mat <- do.call(data.frame, lapply(list(a, b, c), function(x){chron(times. = x)}))

# make the names prettier
names(time_mat) <- c('a', 'b', 'c')
```

which gives you

```
> time_mat
         a        b        c
1 18:12:30 01:50:30 07:54:23
2 06:15:30 09:50:32 22:45:34
3 12:31:40 05:30:43 12:54:23
```

with a class of `times`, which will be consistent in any usage.